# Auto-increment Custom Properties for SOAPUI testSuite

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

I am looking to auto-increment a Custom Property as my SOAPUI test is running. Currently my tests require that there be a unique portion, referred to as UniqueUserPortion, that get incremented as I test for uniqueness in usernames/emails. Is there a way for me to increment this custom property (#Project#UniqueUserPortion), as I will need it to be unique for the next step which is the check for unique username?
Check for unique email:

```
    {  
  "UpdateIdentityRequest":{  
    "guid":"${#Project#UserGUID}",
    "emailAddress": "tomTestUser11@testit.com",
    "screenName": "UpdateUser${#Project#UniqueUserPortion}",
    "inputSystem":"${#Project#UserInputSystem}"
  }
}
```

Check for unique username:

```
    {  
  "UpdateIdentityRequest":{  
    "guid":"${#Project#UserGUID}",
    "emailAddress": "UpdateUser${#Project#UniqueUserPortion}@test.com",
    "screenName": "testUser2011",
    "inputSystem":"${#Project#UserInputSystem}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that internally SoapUI keeps *everything* in XML, and so all properties are just strings. Further, every Groovy Script step get instantiated as a new class, so it cannot "remember" any previous state.

You will have to do something like:

```
// read the property as a string
def uniqueUserPortion = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("UniqueUserPortion")
// convert it to an Integer, and increment
def uniqueUserPortionInc = uniqueUserPortion.toInteger() + 1
// set the property back as string
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("UniqueUserPortion", uniqueUserPortionInc.toString())
// check
log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("UniqueUserPortion")
```