# SOAPUI How do I increment a global variable value

Tags: rest, soap, soapui

I'm using the SmartBear SoapUI 5.2.1 free version.

I have a rather large project and hundreds of web services that require testing. The client wants the testers to use this software and they have no technical experience and no experience with this software. 
So, I have to write up Test Cases for all of these services. What I'm struggling with is that some values that are in the XML content need to be unique and rather than a random number I want to be able to use a Global Variable (idCounter) and increment it every time the service call is ran.

Does anyone know what the syntax would be to get this to execute?
The random does not work because very well because it is ranged 1-100 so it is possible to end up with the same ID resulting in a failed call. Also, it is not an issue with various testers running this because the id gets mashed with the users ID as well making it unique to the user.

I could not find anything so far in my searches.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056482/auto-increment-custom-properties-for-soapui-testsuite)

Comment: I did see that before but it's not clear if properties are the same as global variables. I posted a question in that entry and am awaiting a response. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Can you show how your test is ? its steps? where do you need the counter value or how you want to use it?

Comment: Here is one of the snippets for which I want to use an incremental counter on 
      <record_identifier>${yyyymmdd}${username}000000001</record_identifier> whereas the end portion 00000001 would increment

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have sufficient detail to be able to provide a definitive answer.

The approach that you could take is:

1. Create a test case property, call it maybe `identifier`.
2. Create a transfer properties step, which takes the value, increments it by one, and stores it back in the test case property.
3. In your call, use the new property. Following your comment, the code would look something like this:
   `<record_identifier>${yyyymmdd}${username}${#TestCase#identifier}</record_identifier>`

You can also create a pre-step to reset this property to some known starting value.

Comment: When you say to create a property am I correct that you are referring to the Global Properties area? As for the transfer properties step, I don't understand what to do in regards to that. Same for the pre-step to reset... Can you explain what to do or perhaps provide a link to some Smart Bear tutorial that explains how to do this. Thank you.