# SoapUI - Increase property value for each test case

Tags: testing, properties, soapui

I want to use a property ('currentId') which has a certain start value. For each test case the value should be increased by 1. I can do that by adding an extra test step in each test case which increases the value but that would be much copy paste. The code for that would be (see [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056482/auto-increment-custom-properties-for-soapui-testsuite)):

```
def uniqueUserPortion = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("currentId")
// convert it to an Integer, and increment
def uniqueUserPortionInc = uniqueUserPortion.toInteger() + 1
// set the property back as string
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("currentId", uniqueUserPortionInc.toString())
```

To avoid that copy&paste I've added the code above to the Load Script of the project but it doesn't work:

```
testSuite.testCases.each {
    *code above*
}
```

What can I do to use the code in one script/call for all test cases?
I could define the property as the start value plus the test case ID but that would be a definition in each test case again since I can not reference the #TestCase#ID in project level/property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Issue with what your are trying*

- Load Script of the project is executed once when you import the project into soapui workspace. So, this approach does not work.
- As you rightly mentioned, either you need to have it in a separate step of the each test case or you can add the same code as `setup script`. Yes, it is copy paste only

*It is possible to achieve easily using `SoapUI NG` which pro edition using Event feature.*

Then your next question may be : how to do it in Open Source edition of SoapUI.

Here is an [soapuiExtensions](https://github.com/nmrao/soapuiExtensions) which I did sometime ago which allows you do the same without having to copy paste for each test case in open source edition.

All you need do is have your groovy script into a specific file called 'TestCaseBeforeRun.groovy'. That means, the script is executed before running each test case.

For more details refer [README](https://github.com/nmrao/soapuiExtensions/blob/master/README.md)

> This soapuiExtensions library allows users to have some additional functionality in soapUI(free edition) tool, like soapui pro allows to do something before, after doing something.
>
> For eg: User may want to do something before running a test case or after running a test case etc by implementing appropriate groovy script as required. Allow me to add an example here. Usually user may want to add credentials for the request step automatically, see the script samples/scripts/TestSuiteTestStepAdded.groovy
>
> **How to use this library:**
>
> set SOAPUI_HOME environment variable.
>
> copy lib/SoapUIExtListeners.jar file under $SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory
>
> copy samples/listeners/custom-listeners.xml file under $SOAPUI_HOME/bin/listeners directory
>
> copy samples/scripts directory under $SOAPUI_HOME
>
> And implement appropriate groovy script available under $SOAPUI_HOME/scripts. Refer Mappings file in order to implement respective groovy script.
>
> Note: for windows users, you may need to check %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\soapui.bat which actually overwrites SOAPUI_HOME, need to fix soapui.bat script if requires.
>
> Uses jdk 7, soapUI 4.5.1, and groovy 1.8.9
>
> **Dependency**
>
> log4j

UPDATE: this is realted to the note in the above.

As it was mentioned in the note, soapui.bat overrides SOAPUI_HOME environment variable on windows, needs to be tweaked a bit. May be you want to copy that groovy file under %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\scripts (this is without tweaking soapui.bat)and retry. If your machine is linux then it should work if you copy the groovy file under $SOAPUI_HOME/scripts directory

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Two questions: 1) What exactly must be done by "Refer Mappings file"? In which directory must I copy the file "script.properties" and where must it be referenced? 2) is it possible to use the extension in the SoapUI JUnit test runner?

Comment: This mapping file is used internally, it is given there for user reference, so that he can implement his respective script with the right groovy file name. The extension works based on keys of that property file. You do not have to make any change or place the property file. It is already inside of the jar file. If the jar file is placed under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext, then it should work similarly from soapUI or testrunner. If needed you may refer it to classpath in the IDE

Comment: Have you tried as per the steps? Do you have any issues? In your case, the groovy file name has to be 'TestCaseBeforeRun.groovy' and add your script that you mentioned in the problem into the above file- because you need it work like that ( as name itself explains).

Comment: Thx for the explanation! Yes I've tried and in the log I see that all listeners are added but my script "TestCaseBeforeRun.groovy" in the scripts folder is not called/logged(?). Instead in the log I see: "[CaseRunListener] Dummy script being run, implement required script". Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As it was mentioned in the note, soapui.bat overrides SOAPUI_HOME environment variable on windows, needs to be tweaked a bit. May be you want to copy that groovy file under %SOAPUI_HOME%\bin\scripts (this is without tweaking soapui.bat)and retry.  If your machine is linux then it should work if you copy under $SOAPUI_HOME/scripts directory

Comment: As you see in the property file, there are more actions you can implement using that depending on the need. Good luck. Thank you for trying it patiently.