# Auto-increment Custom Properties for SOAPUI testing

Tags: java, testing, soap, groovy, soapui

```
def TransID = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("TransID")
def TransIDInc = TransID.toInteger()+1 
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("TransID",TransIDInc.toString())
//checkin..
log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("TransID")
```

I want to autoincrement this custom property, and after research and viewing similar issues such as [Auto-increment Custom Properties for SOAPUI testSuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056482/auto-increment-custom-properties-for-soapui-testsuite) I  have tried this solution and created this custom property called TransID which is shown in my request message as `"id": "${#TransID}"` , but whenever i run the groovy script i get log message that value is null thus cannot increment a null value. Does this mean my value is not read from the custom properties?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part works:

```
def TransID = "1"
TransIDInc = TransID.toInteger()+1
assert TransIDInc.toString() == "2"
```

So I think your property is not accerssed correctly. There are different levels or scopes of properties:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("TransID")
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("TransID")
testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("TransID")
```

Make sure you are accessing the correct property, or the property in the correct scope.

You can also try this:

```
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("TransID","${TransIDInc.toString()}")
```

But that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you it showed that my custom property was set in a complete different level, i moved my custom property to the project properties and it works fine!